# Using CMake, how to rebuild Swig wrapper when header file changes

Tags: python, c++, cmake, dependencies, swig

I have a C++ library (called `myfibo`) and I want to make a python binding modue (called `myfibopy`) using CMake and Swig.

The first build works perfectly. But if I rename an exposed C++ function, the python module doesn't build anymore because the Swig wrapper (PYTHON_wrap.cxx) is not regenerated.

I have already tried using SWIG_USE_LIBRARY_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES as explained [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18003) but with no success.

What I am doing wrong?

Here is the toy example to reproduce the error:

**Directory tree**

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── myfibo
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   ├── fibo.cpp
│   └── include
│       └── fibo.hpp
└── myfibopy
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── fibo.i
```

**fibo.hpp**

```
#pragma once
void fib(int n);
```

**fibo.cpp**

```
#include "fibo.hpp"
#include <iostream>

void fib(int n)
{
  int a = 0;
  int b = 1;
  while (a < n)
  {
    std::cout << a << " ";
    a = b;
    b = a+b;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

**fibo.i**

```
%module myfibopy

%include fibo.hpp
%{
  #include "fibo.hpp"
%}
```

**./CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(myfibopy)      

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15) 

add_subdirectory(myfibo)
add_subdirectory(myfibopy)
```

**myfibo/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(myfibo SHARED fibo.cpp)
target_include_directories(myfibo
  PUBLIC
    $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
    $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>   # unused 
)
```

**myfibopy/CMakeLists.txt**

```
find_package(PythonLibs 3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

find_package(SWIG 4.0 REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

set(SRC fibo.i)

set_source_files_properties(${SRC} PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)

swig_add_library(myfibopy LANGUAGE python SOURCES ${SRC})

target_link_libraries(myfibopy PUBLIC myfibo)

# See https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/18003
set_target_properties(myfibopy PROPERTIES SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES TRUE)
```

**First compilation**

```
> cmake -Bbuild -H.
   [...]
> cmake --build build
   [...]
```

Perfect. Now, `build` directory exists and I can play with `myfibopy` module.

**After renaming `fib` into `fib2`** in fibo.hpp and fibo.cpp

```
> cmake --build build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target myfibo
[ 20%] Building CXX object myfibo/CMakeFiles/myfibo.dir/fibo.cpp.o
[ 40%] Linking CXX shared library libmyfibo.so
[ 40%] Built target myfibo
[ 60%] Built target myfibopy_swig_compilation
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target myfibopy
[ 80%] Building CXX object myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/fiboPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
./build/myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/fiboPYTHON_wrap.cxx: In function ‘PyObject* _wrap_fib(PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
./build/myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/fiboPYTHON_wrap.cxx:2968:3: error: ‘fib’ was not declared in this scope
   fib(arg1);
   ^~~
./build/myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/fiboPYTHON_wrap.cxx:2968:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘fib2’
   fib(arg1);
   ^~~
   fib2
myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/fiboPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o' failed
make[2]: *** [myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/fiboPYTHON_wrap.cxx.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:170: recipe for target 'myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [myfibopy/CMakeFiles/myfibopy.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

> `USE_SWIG_DEPENDENCIES`
> New in version `3.20`.
> If set to `TRUE`, implicit dependencies are generated by the swig tool itself. This property is only meaningful for Makefile, Ninja, Xcode, and Visual Studio (Visual Studio 11 2012 and above) generators. Default value is `FALSE`.
> New in version 3.21: Added the support of Xcode generator.
> New in version 3.22: Added the support of Visual Studio Generators.

or

> `USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`
> New in version 3.13.
> If set to `TRUE`, contents of target property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will be forwarded to SWIG compiler. If set to `FALSE` target property INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES will be ignored. If not set, target property `SWIG_USE_TARGET_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` will be considered.

src: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/module/UseSWIG.html

Comment: Yes I tried both but in the wrong CMake function (`set_target_properties` in place of `set_source_files_properties`).
By adding `USE_SWIG_DEPENDENCIES TRUE` in `set_source_files_properties`, the swig wrapper is rebuilt each time a C++ header is modified!
Thank you very much for your answer.

Note: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20) # for USE_SWIG_DEPENDENCIES (Makefiles)

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback ! I may use it too ^^